# Should questions about problems fixed in recent programs versions be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

Let's say there's a bug in MyProgram v1.0, which now dates back to 2013. The bug raised some questions and was solved on version 2014.

The bug today is irrelevant, however the question still appears for queries that involve similar wordings.

People may open that question just to notice that the question and answers in that post are very old and irrelevant.

Should the question be closed? Should I expect that someone trying to use the 2013 version today will face the problem, and that it is worth saving the space vs the time other devs lose today by opening the irrelevant question?

Comment: We don't have a close reason that would be relevant to such a case.

Comment: "*Should I expect that someone trying to use the 2013 version today*" any particular reason you wouldn't expect that?

Comment: I think if the question doesn't include the version number for some reason, editing it in helps clarify things but there isn't a reason to do anything else to it.

Comment: Maybe there's an argument for specific things like web services where you physically *can't* use the bugged version, but other than that people sometimes have to use outdated software for a variety of reasons, and having information on possible workarounds or the minimum upgrade required to fix the bug can be useful for those people. At my last job I was still occasionally dealing with SQL Server 2005 in 2015, for example.

Comment: Some [are *compelled*](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra) (in order to graduate) to use [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) from the early 1990s.